# Force three decimal places when comparing 2 numbers with VBA loop in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a nested loop to compare if there are 7 conceutive numbers in column B that are all above an average (Column D) control limit. The problem is when I compare the actual result with three decimals to the average with two decimals, it compares the result rounded to two decimal places. I have both columns formatted to numbers with 3 decimal places. When I Debug.Print it will prints.

```
Sub seven_above_average()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, count As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim result As Double, limit As Double

lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

count = 0
For j = 12 To lastRow
    For i = j - 7 To j
        result = Cells(i, 2).Value
        limit = Cells(i, 4).Value
        If result >= limit Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next i

    If count >= 7 Then
        For i = j To j - 7 Step -1
            Cells(i, 26).Value = 1
            Debug.Print ("Result = " & result)
            Debug.Print ("Limit = " & limit)
        Next i
    End If
    count = 0
Next j
End Sub
```

All of the data in the picture pass for true in the second If condition even though there are results of 1.389 and 1.388.

```
If count >= 7 then...
```

[image: Picture of some data that are true for the second if]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to scan last 7 cells you have to use:

```
For i = j - 6 To j
```

instead of:

```
For i = j - 7 To j
```

Comment: Lol, of course it was something simple like that. Thanks DisplayName.